# Finding if a list has a minimum list

Tags: python, list

I have a list `S` of lists. All lists in `S` are of the same size and have numbers as entries.

We say that `S` has a minimum if there is a list in `S` such that its entries are not greater than the entries in the corresponding positions in other lists.

For example,

`S = [[4, 5, 6], [3, 6, 9], [1, 4, 6], [2, 5, 8]]` has a minimum (the entries of `[1, 4, 6]` are smaller than the corresponding entries of other lists).

`S = [[4, 5], [3, 6]]` doesn't have a minimum.

Is there  way to do this without checking all possible pairs of lists?

Comment: This seems to be purely an algorithms question rather than anything specific to Python... ?

Comment: If you sort on the first column, the only candidate (or candidates if there are repeats) are at the beginning of the sorted list. And so on.

Comment: Anyway, this seems pretty straightforward, such that I don't understand why there is a question. What's wrong with: figure out what the minimum should look like (hint: can you think of a rule that tells you the only possible value for the first element of that list? The second, etc.?), and then see whether the list contains that candidate?

Comment: "Is there way to do this without checking all possible pairs of lists?" - it's not clear to me what your intended procedure is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```py
s = [[4, 5, 6], [3, 6, 9], [1, 4, 6], [2, 5, 8]]
min_list = [min(x) for x in zip(*s)]
if min_list in s:
    print(f"Min list found: {min_list}")
else:
    print("Min list not found")
```

Output:

```
Min list found: [1, 4, 6]
```

Explanation

First, we calculate the minimum list, `min_list`, and then check to see if this list exists in `s`. But, how does the following works?

```py
min_list = [min(x) for x in zip(*s)]
```

Let us first see the effect of `zip` on `s`:

```
>>> list(*zip(s))
[(4, 3, 1, 2), (5, 6, 4, 5), (6, 9, 6, 8)]
```

So in this case, zip will return a list of three sub-lists. The first sub-list corresponds to all first elements (or in op's terminology: entries). The second sub-list corresponds to to all second elements and so on.

We then apply `min()` to these sub-lists and end up with the minimum list, `min_list`.

Answer (score 1):

You do it pretty well as a generalisation of how you might do it for a scalar.

Pass once through the list to find the minimum at each position.

Then pass a second time through the list to see if one row matches those minima.

```
def minimumList( S ):
   N = len( S[0] )
   minima = S[0].copy()
   for row in S:
       for i, v in enumerate( row ):
           if v < minima[i]: minima[i] = v
   for row in S:
       if row == minima: return True, row
   return False, []


print( minimumList( [[4, 5, 6], [3, 6, 9], [1, 4, 6], [2, 5, 8]]) )
print( minimumList( [[4, 5], [3, 6]] ) )
```

Output:

```
(True, [1, 4, 6])
(False, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to create a list of max values on each position and then compare each sublist to these values:

```py
S = [[4, 5, 6], [3, 6, 9], [1, 4, 6], [2, 5, 8]]

out = [max(l) for l in zip(*S)]
out = next((l for l in S if all(a < b for a, b in zip(l, out))), None)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[1, 4, 6]
```

---

For `S = [[4, 5], [3, 6]]` this prints:

```
None
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the specification, and thus overcomplicated the problem. For example, it seems that we want the first element to be *equal to the minimum* of first elements of the input - not simply "less than the maximum". I understood "entries are not greater than the entries in the corresponding positions in other lists" to mean "... not greater than any of the entries...", because otherwise it would be strange to use the term *minimum* to describe the result. (And yes, the resulting question does seem trivial. It's not clear to me where OP is actually stuck.)

Comment: No, it should be for the entries in the corresponding positions - "entries are not greater than the entries in the corresponding positions in other lists". Which term would you suggest to use in this case? This is how the "minimum" was defined.

Comment: This does not seem to work for [[0, 1],[0, 2]]. It has the minimum: [0,1] but the code says None.